# How to read a picture from a cell of excel document and store into Data table in C#.net?

Tags: c#, excel, kingsoft

I have **(Kingsoft Spreadsheet)** Excel workbook having 15 columns, in the 15th column there is picture saved in a cell. I am reading the excel file and creating a data table with respect to that. All things are working well except to **store picture in data table.** **There can be number of rows each having different image in 15th column.**

C# code:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path, bool hasHeader)
{
    using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            pck.Load(stream);
        }
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();    

        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
        }
        var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;

        for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
        {
           // Inserting Data from Excel to Datatable.
            var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, 15];
            DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
            foreach (var cell in wsRow)
            {
                row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
            }

        }
        return tbl;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I am using Kingsoft spreadsheets.

I am unable to find help to read image from a particular cell of excel.

Please help if anyone can.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: already answerd in Stack Overflow! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993979/openxml-excel-extracting-cell-text-and-image-picture-data

Comment: @PradeepKumar I do think the ExcelPackage is a different library alltogether.

Comment: @PradeepKumar That solution is not working for me, I think that is because I am using OfficeOpenXml. I am unable to find Imagepart and Drawingpart in that package

Comment: It is, it's a free NuGet package called **EPPlus**. Kingsoft should provide documentation otherwise not sure if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

i  think you are not imported namespaces

try importing following namespaces

using System.Drawing;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;

Comment: **@PradeepKumar** Not working with suggested namespaces.