# OpenXML Image not embedded in a cell

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I created a very simple `.xlsx` file for my test:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | world | ! |
| 2 |  | [image: B2_img] | [image: C2_img] |
| 3 |  |  |  |
| 4 | something | [image: B4_img] |  |

To read all text cell with OpenXML, I have no problem. The problem is when I want to read the images of the sheet. By iterating over my `WorksheetPart.DrawingsPart.ImageParts` all the image is listed but not by iterating over my cells.

I can only see the first and the second image and the `CellReference` is wrong. The `B2` image has a reference of `A1`, the second `B1` and the third doesn't appear in this case.

Is exist an other way to retrieve the cell of an `ImagePart` object ?

*To read my images, I used the code on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993979/openxml-excel-extracting-cell-text-and-image-picture-data)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my probleme by using the [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) library:

```cs
foreach (ClosedXML.Excel.Drawings.IXLPicture pic in worksheet.Pictures) {
    Console.WriteLine($"image cell: {pic.TopLeftCell.Address}");
}
```